# networkx set node attributes from python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

I'm trying to write a general function which creates a graph that takes a list of nodes and edges. For each node, there's a set of default attributes, and a set of optional attributes. As the optional attributes can be anything, I'm thinking to use a dictionary to store them. However, it looks like *add_node()* doesn't seems to accept a variable as keyword. Given the below code snippet,

```
import networkx as nx    

optional_attrs = {'ned':1, 'its':'abc'}

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_node('node1')
for k, v in optional_attrs.iteritems():
    g.add_node('node1', k=v)

print g.node(data=True)
```

I get

```
NodeDataView({'node1':{'k':'abc'}})
```

Instead of,

```
NodeDataView({'node1':{'ned':1, 'its':'abc'}})
```

I wonder it is possible to achieve that?

Comment: `g.add_node('node1', attr_dict=optional_attrs)` should do the job. You should read the documentation: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.add_node.html?highlight=add_node#networkx.Graph.add_node

Comment: Also, argument names are taken literally. Even if you have a variable `k` the name of the argument you are passing to `add_node` will always be just the string `"k"`.

Comment: ok. Looks like it creates a dict of dict. Thank you.

Comment: this is not working because attr_dict is computed as an parameter name. Replace attr_dict by blabla will do the exact same thing, except that the parameter name will be blabla.

Answer (score 8):

In general in python if you want to use a `dict` to provide keyword arguments to a function you prepend the dict with `**`.

```
g.add_node('node1', **optional_attrs)
```

You can also add/change node attributes after adding the nodes:

```
g.add_node('node1')
g.nodes['node1'].update(optional_attrs)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [set_node_attributes](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes.html) function, which takes a graph and a dictionary. the keys set of the dic is a subset of the nodes of the graph and its values are data of their corresponding keys.

```
import networkx as nx    
optional_attrs = {'node1':{'ned':1, 'its':'abc'}}
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_node('node1')
nx.set_node_attributes(g, optional_attrs)
print(g.nodes.data())
```

this will output:

```
[('node1', {'its': 'abc', 'ned': 1})]
```

Comment: In this you have to create optional_attrs for every node, quite cumbersome

Answer (score 0):

Create graph only with nodes (no edges) from Pandas dataframe including all attributes (with use of a dictionary):

```python
# create dictionary from pandas dataframe
nodes_dict = nodes_df.set_index('my_id', drop=True).to_dict(orient='index')

# create networkx graph from nodes without attributes
G = nx.Graph() 
G.add_nodes_from(nodes_dict.keys())

# assigne each node its properties from nodes_dict
nx.set_node_attributes(G, nodes_dict)
```

This is a compliation of other smarter guys` advices. My thanks goes to them.